Source of the relationship between the number of parameters and data dimensionality
It is commonly understood that, in classical statistical models, the number of observations should be at least equal to the number of parameters in order to ensure the estimability of those parameters, e.g., if we want to obtain MLE. Otherwise, some parameters are not estimable. Of course, this is not the case in e.g., neural networks.
I have seen explanations in linear regression or linear algebra from a rank perspective.
I would like to ask if one could find the source of this in a more general setup. Many thanks!
